# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null-Keep reloading page and it works

Tags: javascript

[image: Image showing error code and source codes]

I had gone through all old "same" questions but I think this one is different. Some browsers seemed to error more than others. Same browser on different Windows version seemed to error more than others. When error occurred, keep reloading the same page often will get the page to load correctly. When comment out the line that caused the error, other lines would cause the error. Please help and thank you.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

document.getElementById("box76a").value= token[33] + "" ;

<td colspan=4>NPI<input type="text" style="width:80px"  maxlength="10" id="box76a" name="box76a"></td>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("box76a")` is returning `null`, possibly because the code is running before that element is part of the page.

Comment: Where are you putting the code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have window.onload = ProcessReqFlag() as the last line between the SCRIPT tag. The browser loads all the html in the body before it fires the window.onload correct?

Comment: @LearnMe Yup.. Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you formulate your question does not allow for a straight and definitive answer but the comments so far should put you on the path.

Pointy is right on the money, although I'd phrase it as 'definitely' rather than 'probably'.

One further question : where does all that HTML come from ? Any chance that it be generated elsewhere ? That would account for the seemingly randomness.

Now, I can't help but think you didn't anwser completely Praveen Kumar's question while also pointing to a very plausible issue.

As per [MDN page on GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload),

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

I would suspect however that the position of your `<script>` tag within the DOM may have an influence.

Finally, how about doing this the right way ? That is, outsource all your styling options to a .css file and all your JavaScript code in a .js file, leaving only one `<script>` tag in the `<head>` section and nowhere else. Also, again per MDN, it may be preferable to use `window.addEventListener('load',ProcessReqFlag)` instead of `window.onload=ProcessReqFlag()` and specially if, as I would suspect, the underlying is generated dynamically, which means that it may also come with its own event listeners.